# Loss function to penalize different predictions of input from the same domain

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, classification, image-classification

I have a binary image classification task where each image has a certain variable attached to it. I have about 10000 images and 100 unique variable values. It is safe to say that all images with the same variable have the same label. I designed a CNN to classify the images with Pytorch, using Cross Entropy as the loss function.

I want to add a term in the loss function that penalizes the model when two images with the same variable value are classified different. For example, in a batch lets say I have 8 images with the labels = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0] and each with the variable = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2 ,3, 4].

If my model predicts [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], my cross entropy loss will penalize for wrong classification. Now, if my model predicts [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0] and in another case [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], I want to penalize the second case more. How do i manage that?

I tried calculating a term to add to the loss function which calculates for each batch, how many different predictions are made for each of the variables in the batch and finding the mean. But this does not converge.